# How to safely protect input sensing AC Line Voltage

Tags: ac, safety, fuses, detection

I'd like to detect the presence of AC line-level voltages in my PCB project, and I'd like to follow best-practice for doing this. I'm a controls engineer so I'm happy with dealing with mains with chunky discrete components, and I've done a bit of DC electronics and PCB design, but never combined the two so I want to do this as safely as possible.

The input signal might be AC mains across a very small motor, but could also a signal from a motor controller so could be up to a few kHz, with a DC offset from ground of up to 200V (hence why I've labelled the terminals as L1 & L2).

This is my proposed schematic:
[image]

All the AC voltage stuff will be in a separate area of the board from the DC, with no ground plane in that area, and a milled slot under the opto-isolator.

Questions:

1. Anything you'd add? Is this overkill?
2. Capacitor - That's to stop spurious noise, either generated by a controller, motor or noise conducted into the unit. Any suggestions on sizing? Is there a better place to put it?
3. Fuse - what kind to use? My understanding is that it's mainly to stop you getting a short if the MOV fails closed. Is is OK to use a resettable fuse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anything you'd add? Is this overkill?

You don't say what part of the world this is going to be in, but the mains are very nasty in many places.  For better reliability I'd do something like divide the resistor into two and put a bidirectional TVS device at the junction of the two resistors with a breakdown that will clamp before the max current of the opto.  The MOV will absorb energy from the large spikes but the clamping voltage is pretty high.  A TVS will have a better controlled clamping characteristic.

> Capacitor - That's to stop spurious noise, either generated by a controller, motor or noise conducted into the unit. Any suggestions on sizing? Is there a better place to put it?

If you put it across the line as shown, you should use an X-rated capacitor. You could try 0.1uF or a bit larger.  There's no magic formula to pick the value.

> Fuse - what kind to use? My understanding is that it's mainly to stop you getting a short if the MOV fails closed. Is is OK to use a resettable fuse?

If the MOV shorts the resettable fuse won't do you much good.  Maybe for transient overloads it might help, but you have to do the calculations to make sure it will actuate in the time required before damaging anything.  I'd use a fast-blow conventional fuse.

Be sure to observe creepage and clearance distances for the high voltage side, the milled slot will help in that regard.

Comment: Are the MOV and capacitor before the resistor actually adding any value here?

Comment: @user253751 It's debatable.  There could be a spike or surge on the line that's higher than the breakdown voltage of the resistors without the MOV, or higher than necessary to arc across traces for example.  It depends on local power line conditions and reliability requirements.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, and given me plenty to think about. As far as the need for the MOV and capacitor - I wanted to protect the resistor and opto from spikes, but I realise I should be able to source HV resistors and design in suitable clearances fairly easily, and should so may not be necessary. The cap was about noise, but the optocoupler I'm using only goes to 100 kHz, so if I need to filter to lower than that I'll do it on the DC side. My research into TVS diodes has been useful - I may try a design that will respond high and low level signals without swapping the resistor(s).